# Create log group for custom resource lambda in @aws-cdk/aws-s3-deployment

Tags: aws-cdk

I am using the [@aws-cdk/aws-s3-deployment](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v1/docs/aws-s3-deployment-readme.html) module to upload files to s3 during deployment.

The module creates a CustomResource with a Lambda Function to move the files from the assets bucket to my bucket. When the Lambda function runs, it auto-creates a log group, which:

- Has not retention set
- Is not deleted with the stack
- Has not tags (which I need for complicance)

My normal solution is to just create the Log Group myself! But for that I need to name the lambda function (so that I can create the log group with the same name).

@aws-cdk/aws-s3-deployment uses SingletonFunction, which can be passed a function name.
But @aws-cdk/aws-s3-deployment does not pass a function name.

Is there a way to set the name of the lambda function when using @aws-cdk/aws-s3-deployment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The S3-Deployment will create CustomResources that behave like you described upon stack creation and deletion.
To set the retention as well as tags of the log group, you have to create the resource yourself.
The crux is to link it to the underlying lambda function of the custom resource and add the log group as dependency to that lambda.
However, you cannot alter the SingletonFunction. I found a way to get the actual underlying lambda function, link it to a log group by its name, and set the dependencies. This will ensure that the whole stack including the log group will be deleted properly. I hope this will fix your problem!

```
from aws_cdk import (
    aws_ec2 as ec2,
    aws_s3 as s3,
    aws_s3_deployment as s3deploy,
    aws_logs as logs,
    Aws, Stack,
)
from constructs import Construct

class S3AssetDeployment(Construct):
    def __init__(
        self,
        scope: Construct,
        construct_id: str,
        vpc: ec2.Vpc,
        subnets: ec2.SubnetSelection,
    ):

        bucket = s3.Bucket(
            self,
            "AssetsBucket",
            bucket_name=f"fancy-project-assets-{Aws.ACCOUNT_ID}",
        )

        s3_deployment = s3deploy.BucketDeployment(
            self,
            "Assets",
            sources=[s3deploy.Source.asset(sync_directory)],
            destination_bucket=bucket,
            destination_key_prefix=sync_subdir,
            vpc=vpc,
            vpc_subnets=subnets,
        )

        # Find the underlying lambda function of the custom resource and overwrite its name
        all_stack_objects = Stack.of(s3_deployment).node.find_all()
        id_to_find = "Custom::CDKBucketDeployment"
        lambda_id = next(( item for item in [obj.node.id for obj in all_stack_objects] if id_to_find in item ), None)

        custom_resource_lambda = Stack.of(s3_deployment).node.find_child(lambda_id)
        custom_resource_lambda.node.default_child.add_property_override(
            "FunctionName", f"fancy-project-bucket-deployment"
        )

        # Create new log group with the same name and add the dependencies.
        deployment_log_group = logs.LogGroup(
            self,
            "BucketDeploymentLogGroup",
            log_group_name=f"/aws/lambda/fancy-project-bucket-deployment",
            removal_policy=RemovalPolicy.DESTROY,
            retention=logs.RetentionDays.TWO_WEEKS,
        )

        custom_resource_lambda.node.add_dependency(deployment_log_group)
        bucket.node.add_dependency(deployment_log_group)
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually, when something is not exposed in CDK directly, you can still overwrite it by using escape hooks. In this case, you can directly access underlying `SingletonFunction` by referencing `.node.children` array of the `BucketDeployment` class and finding a child that is `SingletonFunction`. You can then overwrite function name or (might be better) just reference it when creating custom log group.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Creating the log group with the same name as the function works by using `SingletonFunction.function_name`. Unfortantly this way there is a dependency which makes the log group being deleted before the function. Then, when the function is run its last time when the CustomResource is deleted, the log group is re-created and remains. But I also see no way to set the name of the Lambda Function when retrieving the SingletonFunction. Maybe do you have any Idea for that?

Comment: Have you tried getting down to `CfnFunction` level and then overwriting `functionName` property? (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_sam.CfnFunction.html#functionname). You can get down to `CfnFunction` level by traversing `.node.children` tree until you get to it.

Comment: Ah, that is basically, what @frdzmn does. Did not get around to implement it till now, but that works. Feels hacky I have to say, but good enough for now. Thanks for the help!